# Receiving RTCP issues within oRTP library

Tags: rtp, rtcp

I am currently getting a segfault when trying to receive RTCP in RECVONLY sessions in oRTP. RTCP works fine when receiving in a SENDRECV session but won't work in RECVONLY sessions.

This is my code. The segfault comes from the function on line 42: err=rtp_session_recv_with_ts(session,buffer,160,ts,&have_more);
This is in the while loop that receives the file.

However, this only occurs on line 32

rtp_session_enable_rtcp(session,TRUE); is set to TRUE.

If I disable RTCP by setting it to FALSE, then the RECVONLY session works.

```
#include <ortp/ortp.h>
#include <bctoolbox/vfs.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cond=1;

void stop_handler(int signum)
{
    cond=0;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    RtpSession *session;
    unsigned char buffer[160];
    int err;
    uint32_t ts=0;
    int stream_received=0;
    FILE *outfile;
    int local_port;
    int have_more;
    int i;
    local_port=atoi(argv[2]);
    outfile=fopen(argv[1],"wb");

    //initialization of the session
    ortp_init();
    ortp_scheduler_init();
    ortp_set_log_level_mask(NULL, ORTP_DEBUG|ORTP_MESSAGE|ORTP_WARNING|ORTP_ERROR);
    signal(SIGINT,stop_handler);
    session=rtp_session_new(RTP_SESSION_RECVONLY);
    rtp_session_enable_rtcp(session,TRUE);
    rtp_session_set_scheduling_mode(session,1);
    rtp_session_set_blocking_mode(session,1);
    rtp_session_set_local_addr(session,"0.0.0.0",local_port,local_port+1);
    rtp_session_set_payload_type(session,0);

    //receiving of incoming file
    while(cond)
    {
        have_more=1;
        while (have_more){
            err=rtp_session_recv_with_ts(session,buffer,160,ts,&have_more);
            if (err>0) stream_received=1;
            /* this is to avoid to write to disk some silence before the first RTP packet is returned*/
            if ((stream_received) && (err>0)) {
                size_t ret = fwrite(buffer,1,err,outfile);
            }
        }
        ts+=160;
    }

    rtp_session_destroy(session);
    ortp_exit();
    ortp_global_stats_display();
    return 0;
}
```

Using gdb to debug, I get this backtrace of the segfault.

```
Thread 1 "err" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd0a53 in concatb (mp=mp@entry=0x606ec0, newm=newm@entry=0x0)
    at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/str_utils.c:337
337     while(newm->b_cont!=NULL) newm=newm->b_cont;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bd0a53 in concatb (mp=mp@entry=0x606ec0, newm=newm@entry=0x0)
    at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/str_utils.c:337

#1  0x00007ffff7bc4ada in append_sdes (full=1 '\001', m=0x606ec0, session=0x602750)
    at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/rtcp.c:397

#2  rtp_session_create_and_send_rtcp_packet (session=session@entry=0x602750, full=full@entry=1 '\001')
    at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/rtcp.c:460

#3  0x00007ffff7bc4d3e in rtp_session_send_regular_rtcp_packet_and_reschedule (
    session=session@entry=0x602750, tc=607522024) at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/rtcp.c:569

#4  0x00007ffff7bc4ebd in rtp_session_run_rtcp_send_scheduler (session=session@entry=0x602750)
    at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/rtcp.c:604

#5  0x00007ffff7bc5085 in rtp_session_rtcp_process_recv (session=session@entry=0x602750)
    at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/rtcp.c:620

#6  0x00007ffff7bca985 in rtp_session_recvm_with_ts (session=session@entry=0x602750, 
    user_ts=user_ts@entry=30880) at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/rtpsession.c:1287

#7  0x00007ffff7bcab24 in rtp_session_recv_with_ts (session=0x602750, 
    buffer=0x7fffffffdf90 "\226ˢT\277\274\350/։c\276e\257\377\377\377\377\376\177\357\377\377\377\277\372\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\356?r\337\301h\225s`\020HvHfJv\312\062\364\332\333\036\364\332fͽL\002\220d\"\206\354b\006\003\060\241cHV21\243Z!\v\r\202\271\214x0\004Pc$\306<\306\006;\270i\352\206l\030`\244@\244\303\071\253\070\"T\356\002\017\004\"8e\377\062\260\225\376\245bG\310\320H", len=160, ts=30880, have_more=0x7fffffffdf8c)
    at /usr/src/debug/ortp-1.0.1-18/src/rtpsession.c:1364

#8  0x0000000000400d15 in main ()
```

From the backtrace, it look as if there is an issue in the library file str_utils.c, but I'm not sure if I'm just forgetting initialize something when setting up a RECVONLY session.

Overall, it looks as though the receiver function on line 42 does not work with RTCP in a RECVONLY session. There are no issues if RTCP is disabled.

Comment: Please extend your question to feature a [mcve]. Also, please try to pinpoint the location of the error to a specific line (e.g. by compiling with debug flags and using a debugger).

Comment: Just noting that I'm getting this too, same conditions, same workaround. Debian libortp13 package, version 1:1.0.2-1.